# Tutorial for uploading a photo from android

Tags: android, flickr, photobucket, photo-upload

Hi there I'm looking for tutorials to upload a photo from an android device to a service such as flickr or photobucket etc. Im not fussy!

(I mean code tutorials, not how to use my android device ;) )

Thanks, Rich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Flickr, I would start exploring the Flickr API at http://www.flickr.com/services/api/.  There is actually a dedicated wrapper for Android, called [flickrj-android](http://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/). This is built upon [flickrj](http://flickrj.sourceforge.net/api/), which has extensive documentation and a good example for implementing calls into your Java code.

For Photobucket, start with exploring the public [Photobucket API](http://pic.pbsrc.com/dev_help/WebHelpPublic/PhotobucketPublicHelp.htm) documentation.

Good luck!